# Rules for deleting questions

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

What are rules for deleting questions?

If a question has many responses, some upvotes and a few hundreds visits, can it still just be deleted? Why is the question not just locked?

---

OK, thanks guys for explanation. I'm not very happy with it, but if this is how Stack Exchange sites works I will at least not be surprised next time. I'm also very disappointed with some comments...

Comment: This question would probably benefit from some examples if you can link to them. (I understand you might not be able to if they're already deleted.)

Comment: No I can't post an example. I have just noticed that my best answer disappeared from my SO profile and the question is also not accessible / visible.

Comment: If you're referring to "Arriving late to a daily stand-up meeting" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610239/), which I think you are, then as well as 5 people voting to close the question, 5 people with sufficient reputation to access the moderator tools voted to delete the question.

Comment: I voted to delete the question because 1) Not specific to programming, 2) discussion-y 3) The 'best' answer was 'There really isn't an answer except the team should decide'.  The answers don't add anything to the corpus of programming knowledge.

Comment: @George: It is specific to programming - if we can discuss design on SO we can also discuss methodologies. The best answer was one of the essential tenets of SCRUM. I have a feeling that you don't understand the SCRUM otherwise you would never wrote point 3 ... If so it is nice to know that you vote for deleting questions which you don't fully understand.

Comment: @LAdislav Arriving late to a meeting is not unique to scrum. "Having the team decide" is hardly unique to Scrum or programming teams in general. The word for it is "Democracy". If you can point out any part of that question that makes it programming specific, I'll vote to undelete.

Comment: @George: How often do you see "Democracy" in SW development? The part of the question which relates the problem to SW development is SCRUM. That guy was told that they are using SCRUM but they don't and answers explained why. Simply this discussion doesn't make sense because we have different point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this concerns [Arriving late to a daily stand-up meeting (10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610239/arriving-late-to-a-daily-stand-up-meeting-closed).

There are some checks in place to prevent the premature deletion of popular content. That particular questions was popular enough that it required two extra votes (for a total of 5) to delete.

Comment: Ok so same people who close the question can also vote for delete? I think this question was also once reopened, doesn't it? So it is not needed more votes for closing after that?

Comment: @Ladislav: Yes, that's possible, but it's not what happened in this case.  Only one of the people who voted to close the question also voted to delete it.  Also, once you vote to close a question you can't vote again if it's reopened.  Five different people need to vote to close it again.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for explanation. It makes sense now.

Comment: @Ladislav: Also not that the threshold for casting delete votes (10k) is higher than that for casting close votes (3k).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be deleted if enough users with high enough reputation vote for them to be deleted.  The reason questions aren't just locked is that only diamond moderators have that ability, and there are relatively few of us.

See the question [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) for more details on deletion.

Comment: Ok, I'm not very happy with it. People spend time to answer the question and it takes only 3 votes to delete it and vaste effort other takes into their answers.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka:  There are questions that are appropriate to SO, and questions that aren't.  Are you arguing that we should leave inappropriate questions around just because some people typed up answers?  If there's a particularly good answer, the very experienced people who can vote to delete will notice that.  If not, what's the loss?

Comment: @David: So questions targeting methodologies are not programming enough? And if you simply don't undestand methodology you can go and delete the question? In SCRUM that question is important - I know that because we had to deal with same problem. And as I know SCRUM is development methodology so where should it be discussed if not on SO?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka:  Two issues here.  First, inappropriate questions should be deleted.  Second, the question was about penalties for being late to a SCRUM stand-up meeting.  Being late for meetings is disruptive in any activity.  So, this was a question related to behavior that's disruptive in any case, but in this case applied to a facet of a programming methodology.  That goes much too far afield for my vote.  Something like "Are there particular reasons why it's bad to be late to a SCRUM stand-up meeting?" would at least be a question about something related to programming.

Comment: @Ladislav: I think most people didn't see that question as targeting a methodology.  The argument was that it was programming related because it was about SCRUM, but it really wasn't even about SCRUM.  It really wasn't even about stand-up meetings either, but the penalty for being late.  So I think a lot of people saw `Programming -> SCRUM -> Stand-up meetings -> meetings -> late penalties` as being too many steps removed from actual programming to be on-topic for SO.  (That's just my opinion, though, I wasn't one of the close/delete voters.)

Comment: Ok. I take it. I hope that you are same restrictive in other questions. In my opinion this was much less disruptive than duplicities where people are lazy to use search before they ask.